# Is there a low degree vertex in planar graphs?

Tags: graphs

A book I read states "Since $G$ is planar, $G$ has a vertex $v$ of degree at most 5".

1. Is this true?
2. Why?
3. Does this theorem have a name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Yes, this is true.
2. It is a direct consequence of [Euler's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph#Euler.27s_formula). The formula entails that the average degree is strictly less than 6, which implies the existence of a vertex of degree at most 5.
3. It doesn't have a name in itself, but Euler's formula is the overall subject.